# Filter on Extended Properties using Microsoft Graph

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/beta/api/singlevaluelegacyextendedproperty_get

In this document, under the "GET resource instances using $filter" section, it has this example:

Get message instance:

```
GET /me/messages?$filter=singleValueExtendedProperties/Any(ep: ep/propertyId eq '{propertyId_value}' and ep/value eq '{property_value}')
```

When I tested it using the graph explorer: https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/graph-explorer

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/messages?$filter=singleValueExtendedProperties/Any(ep: ep/propertyId eq 'String {00062008-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Name TestPropertName' and ep/value ne null)
```

I got this exception:

> "error": {
>   "code": "BadRequest",
>   "message": "Could not find a property named 'propertyId' on type 'microsoft.graph.singleValueLegacyExtendedProperty'.",
>   "innerError": {
>   "request-id": "1224fbd4-f033-4897-b1c0-bef1bf3116f8",
>   "date": "2016-08-12T23:10:57"
>   }
>   }

Why can the `propertyId` not be found?

Moreover, I see the same error when calling

```
GET /me/messages/<id>?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=propertyId eq '{propertyId_value}')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The propertyId property is actually a known bug and we're in the process of rolling out a fix. The fix is to use the id property instead, and should be available to most customers in the next week, if not already available. The docs will also be updated next week.

Cheers!

Angelgolfer-ms

Comment: Thank you. The id property works. When the bug fix starting to roll out next week, would the "id" property continue to be supported? Do I have to make the change from id to propertyId?

Comment: Good to hear that the id property works for you! This is the fix and you're able to access it. You will not have to change id back to propertyId. Also, FYI, the docs have also been updated to reflect using id, instead of propertyId.